# how to restrict length of string present in a line using linux

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have data of the following form:

```
num1    This is a string
num2    This is another string
```

I want to limit length of all strings which are after the first tab..such that length(string)<4. Therefore, the output which I get is:

```
num1    This is a string
num2    This is another
```

I can do this using python. But I am trying to find a linux equivalent in order to achieve the same.

Comment: You say "length(string)<4", but I don't see anything in your output that's consistent with that; for example, `"This is another"` is 15 characters long.

Comment: This is almost the same as http://stackoverflow.com/q/19804806/3165552

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), by columns :

```
$ awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $4}' file
```

or with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed)  :

```
sed -r 's@^(\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+).*@\1@' file
```

or by length using [cut](/questions/tagged/cut) :

```
$ cut -c 1-23 file
```

Comment: Yes you are right...i have a very big file(1 TB)..and i want to automate the procedure...instead of doing the same 1 line at a time manually

Comment: is there some way of iteraing through each line of file..along with cut

Comment: That's the default behaviour of `cut` if you provide a file as argument.

Answer (score 35):

In bash, you can use the following to limit the string, in this case, from index 0 to index 17.

```
$ var="this is a another string"

$ echo ${var:0:17}

this is a another
```

Comment: Yes you are right...i have a very big file..and i want to automate the procedure...instead of doing the same 1 line at a time manually

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to truncate strings on word boundaries, you could use `fold` with the -s option:

```
awk -F"\t" '{
    printf "%s\t", $1; system(sprintf("fold -sw 17 <<< \"%s\" | sed q", $2))
}'
```

The drawback is `fold` and `sed` need to be called for each line (`sed q` is the same as `tail -n1`).